# Setting up VPN on Windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, vpn

I'm trying desperately to set up VPN on my windows server 200 r2.
The server already has domain controller on it.

I go through the usual steps for example as shown here 
http://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/server-2008-r2-pptp-vpn-with-1-nic.html
However Im confused as to what IP address to use to connect from the clients. If i use the static range i put in i.e. 192.168.65.100 - 192.168.65.200 it just times out when I ping it from a client computer.

If i try and ping the IPv4 address shown from IPCONFIG on the server I just get Destination host unreachable.

I also just get a time out when I try and ping the external IP address of the server, found using whatsmyip.com.

In short in case you havent already guessed i'm a complete novice when it comes to setting up the vpn network and would really appreciate one of you experts to part ways with some of your advice :)

Thanking you massively in advance as I've wasted about a week on this!!!!

p.s. i've used 3rd party softwares like Logmein hamachi but Im experiencing no end of problems with them and their support forum doesnt reply to me at all.

Thanks guys...

Comment: 1. You won't be able to ping the RRAS ip address pool unless you have a VPN client connected and using one of those addresses. They're not "real" ip addresses assigned to the server. They're a pool of ip addresses that the server assigns to VPN clients. 2. What server ip address are you trying to ping? The external or the internal ip address? If you're trying to ping the external ip address and you don't allow inbound pings then that's not going to work. 3. Ping is not a VPN testing tool so stop using it as such. 4. Pinging the server internal address and failing is your most immediate problem

Comment: Start with the physical layer of the server. Do you have a good physical connection? Work your way up to layer 3. Does the server have a valid ip address on your internal subnet? Can the server ping any internal hosts?

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't install your VPN server on a Domain Controller.  In general, don't install anything else on your Domain Controller.
2. The static range you reference is the range of IP the clients get assigned when they connect.  Not the address they connect to.  The address they connect to will need to be a publicly-routed addres, not a private IP.

   - Going to back to #1, you don't want to open up your Domain Controller to the internet.  So don't install a VPN server on it.
3. If you can't connect to the external address of your server, check your firewall... you do have this firewalled, right?  And your network config - I assume this is NATed off, make sure you're forwarding the ports and services to the server they need to go to.
4. Get a consultant or expert to set this up for you.  You seem hopelessly over your head here, and it will be cheaper in the long tun to get it set up right than to get it set up into a mess and have t fix it later.